# Mathematica not optimized for macOS?

Tags: front-end, mac-os-x

On launching Mathematica (11.3.0.0) on macOS 10.13.4 I get a warning that it is ["not optimized" for High Sierra](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208436). Is this a known issue being addressed?

Comment: Apparently, you have installed an (ancient?) 32-bit version of Mathematica. Don't you have access to a 64-bit version?

Comment: Please include your version of *Mathematica*, for completeness.

Comment: I am running MMA ver 11.3 on macOs 10.13.4. I never got any message/warning when starting it up :((..., I suggest you contact Wolfram support...

Comment: This is going to happen until Wolfram provides a 64-bit version for macOS, I think.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: 11.3.0.0

Comment: I found this, in which Wolfram acknowledges they have not released a 64 bit version of Mathematica, but are working on it: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/37287

Comment: Ah, it's the FrontEnd. That isn't optimized anyway...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Mma 11.3's Front End is still 32-bit (!!!)  The kernel is of course 64-bit, but the FE is 32-bit, which limits it to 2 GB of memory and causes me trouble by crashing whenever more than that is needed.

Comment: @user6014 Mathematica consists of two components: the computation kernel, which has been 64-bit for a very long time, and the "front end" (i.e. the GUI), which is still 32-bit. It's quite misleading to say that "Mathematica is not 64-bit". The most important part, and the part that benefits the most, has been 64-bit-only on OS X for many years now.

Comment: @szabolcs Thanks for making the clarification, that is an important distinction

Comment: I find it kind of amusing that any professional level application like Mathematica is still 32 bit on Mac OS X, I wrote the 64 bit stack for OpenGL for MacOS back in 2004? It's been a very long time. The kernel was 32 bit for a long time it just looked at all clients as 64 bit clients then when the kernel switched to 64 bit it was pretty seamless. But really... the front end is 32 bit?

Comment: Looking at the credits for Mathematica its full of external software libraries and components. I would imagine it is a fairly large uphill battle to bring these inline as 64 bit components... but there really is no choice, you have to compile them individually as 64 bit with corrections or replace the functionality they provide with new code.

Comment: On a related note, I never understood why more reputation points are required to comment on SE than to respond. Re replacement of functionality, that is exactly the project to which @JFultz referred (we clearly slipped a bit on the delivery, for reasons unrelated).

Comment: Todays date is 3/25/20. Just when is the 64-bit going to be available? Schrodinger's Cat.

Comment: @BillWilliamson Version 12 is already available for nearly a year, and 12.1 is just available for a week or two. Both are 64 bits.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This message is a warning delivered by High Sierra that the application you're running is a 32-bit application.  In our case, it's specifically referring to the Mathematica front end, which is not only 32-bit, but also still running against the legacy Carbon APIs for accessing the windowing system.

The Mathematica bundle also contains a small number of other 32-bit binaries, but the kernel is fully 64-bit, and has been since even before macOS could support 64-bit GUI applications (since the kernel is not, in fact, a GUI application).

Based upon what we know about how High Sierra delivers this warning, you should receive it once only for any given app bundle.

We're actively developing a 64-bit Cocoa version of the front end, as well as ports of other binaries which remain unported.  I'm not ready to suggest a date when we'll release this, but I'm quite confident it'll be sometime this calendar year.

---

**Update:** Version 12.0 and later releases are fully 64-bit, and the v12 front end is a completely native 64-bit Cocoa app.  Furthermore, version 12 (the latest version as of this writing) has been tested with and is fully supported for macOS 10.15 (Catalina).

Comment: Very interesting; should we expect a performance boost of the front end in the 64bit version?

Comment: @QuantumDot it depends upon what you mean by "performance".  If you're asking whether it will be faster, I don't yet have enough information to say.  If you're asking about stability, it will certainly prevent a class of crashes caused by memory exhaustion.  And we'll be able to avoid a class of Carbon-layer bugs that Apple is no longer interested in fixing.  And we'll be able to adopt some macOS app features that simply aren't available to Carbon apps (that's not to say all such features will be ready on day one, though).

Comment: Do you mean like the crash that happens if I click on the `+` button in the summary box of `Compile[{x},Evaluate@Array[y,100000]]`?  (my guess is that this is an out-of-memory crash)

Comment: Can't wait for the prerelease ... whenever I work either with large `MeshRegions` or large images, I need to be prepared for the FE crashing eventually (due to the 2 GB memory limit).  Forgetting a semicolon can easily result in an immediate crash.

Comment: Is the windows frontend also 32 bit?

Comment: @user13892 there are 32- and 64-bit versions of the Windows front end (and kernel). The installer installs both and the launcher automatically launches the best one for your system.

Comment: @QuantumDot, a couple of months ago, I did some tests on the latest 64-bit Mac FE, which is now in prerelease and should be shipping shortly, and I found that for most FE-specific operations there was a modest, across-the-board speed-up.  I was doing things that stressed broad portions of the system like opening large notebooks with varied content, cycling the help viewer, etc. and finding that operations were taking around 40% less time. It wasn't a result I had expected, and I'm certain there's specific areas of functionality where that number won't hold, but I'm happy to see it's the case.

Comment: @JohnFultz  Very nice!  I would be interested in a one-week trial version to make sure my public packages continue to function in the new front end.  Is that something I can request at the User Portal?

Comment: @QuantumDot if you send me your full name and email to arnoudb@wolfram.com I will get you added