# Wolfram Mathematica on mac os Mojave

Tags: warning-messages

I found out that Apple stop support programms with 32-bit architecture in new Mac OS Mojave, has anyone already updated??? I want to see new dark mode, but if WM will stop working it will be a problem...[image]

Comment: 32-bit apps will continue to work in Mojave but not in future versions of  OS X. In the upcoming version, the OS X frontend is 64-bit, so this will not be a problem in future versions of Mathematica.

Comment: Google says that Mojave still supports them, it is the last version. And as for MMA: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/170965/5478

Comment: No problems with Mathematica 11.3.0 on Mojave

Comment: Mathematica 12.0 is fully 64-bit now and I'd expect it to work past Mojave, after Apple drops 32-bit support.

Answer (score 2):

I have updated to Mojave and fresh *Mathematica* installation works well for me. Though, the dark mode is not enabled for *Mathematica* (it is still white).

[image]

Comment: You should email WRI and request this as a feature for v12!

Answer (score 1):

Mojave officially still supports 32-bit applications, but it will be the last release of macOS to do so. Apple has confirmed this time and time again.

Answer (score 0):

After last update of mojave 10.14.4, WM don't work. If I right understand it is connect that Front-End of WM work in 32-bit regime.

Comment: I have been using several versions of Mathematica (from 10.0 onwards) on macOS 10.14.4 without problems.  The problem you see may not be due to the macOS update. I suggest you contact Wolfram Support and ask for help in sorting this out.

Comment: Wolf. Mathematica don't start, it hangs on start.  I don't see front-end...